# Problem in NSData in downloading

Tags: iphone, ipad

i have one file with name My book.doc .but at time of downloading from url ,NSData showing 0 bytes.
Here is my code

```
   NSString *imagelist = @"http://SomeUrl/My book.doc";
NSData *yourdoceFileData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imagelist]];
  NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *yourFilePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:reString];
[yourdocFileData writeToFile:yourFilePath atomically:YES];
```

if i remove whitespace in filename and also in string ,then it works properly.
tell me 1 thing is it possible for download with whitespace between filename.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to encode the URL.  Spaces are not valid in an URL.  A space character is '%20", so this should work:

```
NSString *imagelist = @"http://SomeUrl/My%20book.doc";
```

I use the following function to do the encoding:

```
- (NSString *)urlEncodeValue:(NSString *)str
{
    NSString *result = (NSString *) CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(kCFAllocatorDefault, (CFStringRef)str, NULL, CFSTR("?=&+"), kCFStringEncodingUTF8);
    return [result autorelease];
}
```

Comment: i have to download file from server.for this i made xml. so i change filename to @"My%20book.doc" in both server and xml. but  its not work

Comment: Don't change it on the server.  Just in the NSString you're using for the URL.  Or leave the string along and %-encode it before you use it.

Answer (score 0):

URL's should not contain whitespace. Replace with space with "%20":

NSString *imagelist = @"http://SomeUrl/My%20book.doc";

Answer (score 0):

Replace the space with a "%20", or use the more general `stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding` method of `NSString`.